# Converting 1 minute data to 5 minutes using R

Tags: r

I am trying to convert 1 minute data for 5 minutes in R using PROXISct. But I am unable to convert it.
My data is in this format.

```
       Date   Time   Price   Volume    No.of.trades
1  01-06-2012 09:15 4901.895 283550         1286
2  01-06-2012 09:16 4907.046 140000          831
3  01-06-2012 09:17 4904.140  96900          639
4  01-06-2012 09:18 4900.609  84350          553
5  01-06-2012 09:19 4900.067  76450          516
6  01-06-2012 09:20 4898.378  84900          551

dt_tm <- as.POSIXct(paste(x[,1], x[,2]),
                format="%d-%m-%Y %H:%M", tz="UTC")
cable <- xts(x[,3:5], order.by=dt_tm)

                    Price    Volume    No.of.trades     
2012-01-07 09:15:00 6054.890 139750          787
2012-01-07 09:16:00 6051.176  56550          335
2012-01-07 09:17:00 6045.232 127400          691
2012-01-07 09:18:00 6039.950  59950          374
2012-01-07 09:19:00 6042.292  55450          214
2012-01-07 09:20:00 6044.140  53600          246
```

After this step I am getting a different type series, which is not there in my data.
Further, I have to use this code to convert my data to 5 minutes,

```
colnames(cable)[1] <- "CLOSE"
trades5 <-to.minutes5(cable, indexAt='startof', name=NULL)
```

Please correct me where I am doing wrong, and suggest me if there is any other way of converting this type of data to 5 minutes.

I am still facing problem related to data.date structure in my data is day-month-year, you have suggested to swap the day and months, i did the same and get the desired outcome but in head it is fine but when i am looking for tail, i am finding some problem in it.initally tail was

```
Date        Time      Price     Volume    No.of.trades
91561 31-05-2013 15:25 6004.504  86550          622
91562 31-05-2013 15:26 6003.709 117750          651
91563 31-05-2013 15:27 6000.656 160950          856
91564 31-05-2013 15:28 5997.516 215950         1191
91565 31-05-2013 15:29 5995.305 303200         1784
```

now with the following code

```
dt_tm <- as.POSIXct(paste(x[,1], x[,2]),
    format="%m-%d-%Y %H:%M", tz="UTC")
ct <- cut(dt_tm, breaks="5 mins")
ct_tm <- as.POSIXct(as.character(ct))
cable <- xts(x[,3:5], order.by=ct_tm)
head(cable)
                    Price         Volume          No.of.trades
2012-01-06 09:15:00 4901.895        283550         1286
2012-01-06 09:15:00 4907.046        140000         831
2012-01-06 09:15:00 4904.140        96900          639
2012-01-06 09:15:00 4900.609        84350          553
2012-01-06 09:15:00 4900.067        76450          516
2012-01-06 09:20:00 4898.378        84900          551
```

but when i am looking for tail
    tail(cable)

```
      Price         Volume          No.of.trades
<NA> 6004.504         86550           622
<NA> 6003.709         117750          651
<NA> 6000.656         160950          856
<NA> 5997.516         215950         1191
<NA> 5995.305         303200         1784
<NA> 5991.419         550            8
```

kindly help me where now i am going wrong.

Comment: The formating of the date must be incorrect - i.e. if you would parse `2007-31-01` as `year-day-month`, it would be OK, but parsing it as `year-month-day` would produce `NA` value. I guess that is whats going on here - somewhere you are trying to parse values, which are "forbiden". Try different format, if the problem persists

Answer (score 2):

I think you may be formating your data incorrectly - swapping day and month.

```
dt_tm <- as.POSIXct(paste(x[,1], x[,2]),
            format="%m-%d-%Y %H:%M", tz="UTC")
```

Converting to 5 minutes data frame can be achieved like this:

```
# cut dt_tm to 5 minutes intervals
ct <- cut(dt_tm, breaks="5 mins")
# convert to POSIXct
ct_tm <- as.POSIXct(as.character(ct))
# aggregate
cable <- xts(x[,3:5], order.by=ct_tm)

                    Time    Price      Volume  
2012-01-06 09:15:00 "09:15" "4901.895" "283550"
2012-01-06 09:15:00 "09:16" "4907.046" "140000"
2012-01-06 09:15:00 "09:17" "4904.140" " 96900"
2012-01-06 09:15:00 "09:18" "4900.609" " 84350"
2012-01-06 09:15:00 "09:19" "4900.067" " 76450"
2012-01-06 09:20:00 "09:20" "4898.378" " 84900"
```

Comment: could you rather edit your question? this is fairly difficult to read