# converting 15 minute intervals to hourly intervals in R

Tags: r, date, parsing, time

In the example below, we can see that for every 4 lines, an hour passes. The timestamps are shown in 15 minute increments.

```
                   timestamp   size
1  2013-10-29T00:00:00-05:00    200
2  2013-10-29T00:15:00-05:00    130
3  2013-10-29T00:30:00-05:00    300
4  2013-10-29T00:45:00-05:00    300
5  2013-10-29T01:00:00-05:00    323
6  2013-10-29T01:15:00-05:00    675 
7  2013-10-29T01:30:00-05:00    234
8  2013-10-29T01:45:00-05:00    423
9  2013-10-29T02:00:00-05:00   1123
```

I would like to extract only the time (remove the date) from the timestamp.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21821408/converting-1-minute-data-to-5-minutes-using-r)?

Comment: A little bit unclear, what would be your output based on this input?

Comment: Not sure how to do it with R, but you could parse the minute value from the data value.  Whenever its value is zero capture that result.  For some reason I feel like this could be referred to as a module?

Comment: @Sotos that question you referenced is close to mine, im just having a hard time figuring out hour to split the date from the time in the timestamp

Comment: you mean split it in two columns? You can also do this `split(df, sub(':.*', '', df$timestamp))` to split the whole df by hour

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you guys need to parse your date/time value into specific values.  If you do this you can check for when your value equals whatever and pull values.  For example you want every 15 I would do module, value % 15 or something similar. Or if you want something with an hour value, parse date/time and get the minutes.  If minutes equals 0, grab that value.  Here are some articles how to do this in R. 
***Very Specific:*** https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/vignettes/lubridate.html 
***General Read:*** http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/parsing-datetimes/